# Forcing DirectoryEntry to Unbind an LDAP Connection

Tags: ldap, directory, unbind, directoryentry

I'm coding a C# application trying to bind an LDAP server via DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry. There are several DirectoryEntry objects accessing to the server. I saw that all of these objects use the same connection on the server (I check it out by TCPViewer and saw only one ldap connection). Although I think I'm closing all objects by myDirectoryObject.Close() method, there is still an open connection on the server. Is it possible to force the connection to close the open connection to a server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the control at the connection level, I think you should use [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257186%28VS.90%29.aspx).